Pandas new column based on other dataframe with matching condition
suppose I have two dataframes:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 2, 3], 'Id':['A','B','C'], 'Country': ['US', 'CA', 'DE']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'US': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'CA':[5, 10, 15, 20], 'DE':[100, 200, 300, 400]})

I would like to add a column to df1 that is equal to the value in df2 for the corresponding Country and corresponding date.
Desired result should look like that:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 2, 3], 'Id':['A','B','C'], 'Country': ['US', 'CA', 'DE'], 'New':[10, 15, 400]})


import pandas as pd

# Sample data

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'day': [0, 2, 3], 'Id':['A','B','C'], 'country': ['US', 'CA', 'DE']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'day': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'US': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'CA':[5, 10, 15, 20], 'DE':[100, 200, 300, 400]})

# now the day column as index df2 

df2.set_index('day', inplace=True)

# Add df1

df1['Value'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2.at[row['day'], row['country']], axis=1)
    
print(df1)


Thanks! That is a valid solution using apply vs. merger

@CTXR but keep in mind that apply is very slow

should vetorized  those ops

@joana apply is the opposite of vectorization, this uses a python loop and creates a temporary Series for each row, which is why it is so slow.

@mozway Are there any circumstances we should opt for apply instead of merge? I guess Merge could create memory issues if dataframes are big? But apply would be extremely slow in that case too.

For this operation, no, merge is efficient. I also added another option in my answer that should be similar to apply but vectorized. It does create a large 2D intermediate however if there are a lot of duplicated dates.

melt and merge:
out = df1.merge(df2.melt('Date', var_name='Country', value_name='New'),
                on=['Date', 'Country'], how='left')

Or two-DataFrames indexing lookup:
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df1['Country'])

df1['New'] = (df2.set_index('Date')
              .reindex(index=df1['Date'], columns=cols)
              .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), idx]
             )

Output:
   Date Id Country  New
0     0  A      US   10
1     2  B      CA   15
2     3  C      DE  400


Works well, thank you!
